Guidelines for Structuring Modules and Services in NestJS
I am new to NestJS and I am having trouble understanding the guidelines for creating new modules versus creating new services within the same module. Specifically, I am unsure when to decide to create a new module or keep functionality within an existing module.
For example, I have the following methods:

findUserById()
createUser()
deleteUserById()
updateUserById()
signin()
signup()
logout()
My initial thought was that the first four methods are CRUD operations for the User entity, so they should be in a module called UserModule. The registration and authentication methods should be in a separate module called AuthenticationModule.

However, I noticed that there is shared logic between signup() and createUser(), since signing up involves creating a new user. This made me wonder if they should be included in the same service or if I should keep them in separate modules but import the UserModule into the AuthenticationModule and add the UserCrud service to the providers section of the AuthenticationModule.
In React, there is a section in the docs called "Thinking in React," which provides guidelines on structuring components. I am looking for similar guidance for NestJS but have not found a good resource.
Question:
What are the guidelines for deciding when to create a new service versus creating a new module in NestJS?

From my experience these guidelines are basic software engineering principles related to Coupling and Cohesion.

Coupling refers to the degree of interdependence between software modules.


Cohesion refers to the degree to which elements within a module work together to fulfill a single, well-defined purpose


A good software will have low coupling.
A good software design will have high cohesion

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/software-engineering-coupling-and-cohesion/
Depending on the use cases you'll be working on it's your choice if you want create a new service or a new module (with it's own service) and this will be highly influenced by important factors that will determine the maintainability, scalability, and reliability of a system.
For example, in your current project you might be alright if your Auth Service is inside you User Module for now but are they really related? If the Auth service is in charge of authentication only and it makes a query and returns a token is it really part of the UserCrud Module that's just in charge of manipulating and querying user data? They are actually independent from each other if you think about it so there's a reason why this should be independent from each other.
Another thing you should consider is how scalable will your system be? Maybe in the future you want to enable some other type of authentication which is not related to your user table, maybe a process the involves a third-party authentication or authenticating an external API that hits your endpoints.
If you have every single service in the same module it won't be very cohesive. On the other hand if you have multiple modules that are constantly communicating between each other and calling functions all over the place you would have high coupled modules which wouldn't be the best approach since it's going be harder to maintain on the long-run and make your system more complex.
Let's say later on you want to add a "Send email feature", the best approach would be to create an independent Email Module in charge of sending the message even though it is slightly related to the user table since the user has en email field. Email Module is in charge of sending messages and that's the purpose it fulfills in your system, maybe later on you want to send emails to people that aren't users of your platform. It's all subjective and it all depends on how the system will evolve in the long-run
Conclusion, it's best to have decoupled modules (and services) which will fulfill a single purpose to make it:

Scalable
Maintanable
Reliable

